# In Sonoma 14.1 finder opens a dialog which cannot get the focus, how to deal with it?

Tags: finder, sonoma

After reinstalling and migrating from my former MacBook Pro, the finder cannot open up. It has its dialog asking to reopen all previous open window or not but I cannot click on either buttons.

What can I do?

Btw, unable to get focus on it with tabs and Mission Control either. I even reinstalled Sonoma without effect). Killing the task relaunch finder and it opens up the dialog again

[Update] actually, and to be more accurate, the mouse pointer manage to move the dialog box around, it is the two button that cannot gain focus and therefore I can click either one.

Removing all ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist* did not fix anything

Comment: Can you use Mission Control to get focus on the dialog? Can you Force Quit the Finder?

Comment: Unable to get focus on it (I even reinstalled Sonoma without effect). Killing the task relaunch finder and it opens up the dialog again.

Comment: You can't click on the window at all to bring it to focus? Or Command ` (backtick)?

Comment: I would look at deleting some of the Finder plist preference files in the user Library/Preferences folder.

Comment: Thanks I did it but nothing changed, still the same dialog with unactionable buttons

Comment: Have you tried logging in in safe mode? If you do and Finder loads correctly then you know the issue is with the migrated user.

Comment: Yes, I did restart in safe mode and the finder behaves the same way

Comment: I'd suggest deleting the contents of the Finder's Save Application State folder.

Answer (score 1):

Dialog I created another user account (without my initial data), switched to the account (without closing actual account session) and played a bit with the finder, which behaved as expected.
Then I switched backed to my account, and hallelujah, the finder dialog had its button working. I clicked on “do not reopen” and finder opened up.
Looks like working normally now.
Not sure what was happening. Keep a close look at how the finder will do in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue after upgrading to "MacOS Sonoma", and this problem can be solved by activating the "Keyboard navigation" setting:

[image]

I hope it helps :-) Thanks!